# Django - custom filter that calls a method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know that you can't call a method using a filter because it does it based on the DB.  So I'm trying to write a custom filter.

```
    @staticmethod
    def custom_filter(obj,method_name, arg=False):
        for i in obj.objects.all():
            if getattr(i, method_name)() == arg:
                yield i
```

I can get this to work if I call:

```
MyModel.custom_filter(MyModel,'my_method','myarg')
```

however, I can't chain these together like regular filters.

I could do something like this:

```
@staticmethod
def custom_double_filter(obj,method1,arg1,method2,arg2):
    for i in obj.objects.all():
        if getattr(i, method1)() == arg1 and getattr(i,method2)()==arg2:
            yield i
```

but I'd like it to support an arbitrary number of filters AND some of the methods have their own arguments

```
@staticmethod
def custom_double_filter(obj,method1,arg1,method2,arg2):
    for i in obj.objects.all():
        if getattr(i, method1)(<may need to pass an argument>) == arg1 and getattr(i,method2)()==arg2:
            yield i
```

EDIT: So I tried to make a custom manager like so:

```
class GroupManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def custom_filter(self,method_name, arg=False):
        results = []
        for i in self.all():
            if getattr(i, method_name)() == arg:
                results.append(i)
        return results
```

This works for one call to custom_filter but obviously since I'm returning a list, I can't chain these calls together.  I need a way to be able to pass arbitrary numbers of parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters aren't really part of your model class.

They're part of a Manager associated with your Model class.  The default manager instance is named `objects`.

You can, however, add managers with fancy filters.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/managers/

When you write your own, customized manager, be sure to read this section: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types so that your new manager does everything the default manager did, as well as your new, fancy filter.

> I want the filter to be able to call any method or combination of methods

That's a bit crazy, but you might be able to make it work.  Calling "any method" means that you have to prepare and pass in all the required arguments to that method function.  It starts to get into too much `*arg` and `**kw` metaprogramming for my taste.

I would suggest that the manager is not "generic" but has methods in the manager that -- specifically -- match the underlying model.  You're not going to call them `filter`, either. you're going to map them to the model in a simple way.

I think that simple manager methods that map to simple model methods is about the best you're going to do.

Also, you have good old-fashioned Python list comprehensions and generator functions.  We use this.

```
def our_special_filter( some_queryset ):
    for row in some_queryset:
        if row.aMethod(): yield row

result= our_special_filter( SomeModel.objects.filter(...) )
```

Yes.  It breaks the nice fluent API style.  But it's quite simple and works nicely.

Comment: That looks like the place where I would probably want to put the filter.  How would I go about writing the actual filter though?  I want the filter to be able to call any method or combination of methods

Comment: Is it possible to make something return a queryset?  If it were I could chain my filters together.

Comment: @JPC: "make something return a QuerySet?" Not easily.  "because it does it based on the DB".  There's no need.  You can more easily add your filters outside the `filter().filter()` fluent API style of the QuerySet.